# WHMCS Cannot redeclare _createCustomer()

Tags: php, plugins, whmcs

I added the ResellerClub module in my WHMCS but it came with a few bugs in the files, most have managed to solve this but have not found the flaw.
When you add the folder that the WHMCS module can not edit or add new products.

WHMCS configured to display the error and the following message appears:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare _createCustomer() (previously declared in /home/user/public_html/painel/modules/servers/resellerclubmdhostingin/resellerclubmdhostingin.php:483) in /home/user/public_html/painel/modules/servers/resellerclubvpsus/resellerclubvpsus.php on line 486
```

I tried a few things but I could not...
Has anyone seen this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states, you're redeclaring a function `_createCustomer`, and this causes a fatal error.

You have 2 declarations:

```
/home/user/public_html/painel/modules/servers/resellerclubmdhostingin/resellerclubmdhostingin.php:483
/home/user/public_html/painel/modules/servers/resellerclubvpsus/resellerclubvpsus.php:486
```

You should check the files and remove one declaration or wrap the one in `resellerclubvpsus.php:486` into:

```
if(!function_exists('_createCustomer')) {
   function _createCustomer(/* ... */){
       // ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I thank the guidelines and apologize for having published the wrong way, I'm new to the site and ended up spending despecebido how to post another question.

I realized the change that Alexander guided me but appeared the following error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare _get_order_details() (previously declared in /home/user/public_html/painel/modules/servers/resellerclubmdhostingin/resellerclubmdhostingin.php:589) in /home/user/public_html/painel/modules/servers/resellerclubvpsus/resellerclubvpsus.php on line 577
```